# Is there any provision in AWS IoT Core to fetch previous shadow state? Is there any APIs / history of configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

Is there any way to check the previous shadow desired state or history data of configuration?

Comment: I don't think so. I have only seen it referenced as "the" shadow state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Thing Shadow only includes the latest desired and reported states. [There is a version field you can use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-shadow-document.html#versioning), but this is only for synchronization purposes like ensuring a device doesn't overwrite a newer version of its shadow.

Answer (score 0):

You may however save the shadow history manually by creating a rule which forwards the shadow messages from the MQTT topic to your database of choice.

But if you want to follow the AWS well architected framework, I would put the shadow content that you need to see as a history in a separate MQTT channel (your devices could even send the info over shadow topic + over MQTT on a separate topic, maybe via the Basic Ingest topic to avoid additional fees).

Ask me if you need more details.